# Google Script Import Data Based on Filter Criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import

//I am trying to import data for specific team members based on project status. The code works well, if only pulling into 1 tab, but not all 12 tabs. Also, if you could provide insight on how to match to column headers, the data could sometime vary from sheet to sheet.  The data will be on a trigger and update, but the data should not overwrite data that still meets the criteria setup within the code. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Data Sheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ/edit#gid=602022015

Target Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFRs48JHCrH82msFkGrZ8iqDpyAdXww1e1EZYf6FRx8/edit#gid=0

```
function myFunction() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1X_NBWq1m9iBxvYXhy2wcttHanvPFPlAOJWgbbKbJimQ'); //replace with source ID
var ss1 = sss.getSheetByName('January'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('February');
    var ss2 = sss.getSheetByName('March');
  var ss3 = sss.getSheetByName('April');
  var ss4 = sss.getSheetByName('May');
  var ss5 = sss.getSheetByName('June');
  var ss6 = sss.getSheetByName('July');
  var ss7 = sss.getSheetByName('August');
  var ss8 = sss.getSheetByName('September');
  var ss9 = sss.getSheetByName('October');
  var ss10 = sss.getSheetByName('November');
  var ss11 = sss.getSheetByName('December');

var range = ss.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range = ss.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range1 = ss.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range2 = ss2.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range3 = ss3.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range4 = ss4.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range5 = ss5.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range6 = ss6.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range7 = ss7.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range8 = ss8.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range9 = ss9.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range10 = ss10.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
  var range11 = ss11.getRange('A:Z');      //assign the range you want to copy
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 1
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
if(rawData[i][1] == "Completed")    // Check to see if column 6 says completed if not skip it
  if(rawData[i][2] == "Bob")
{
data.push(rawData[i])
}
}

var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1oFRs48JHCrH82msFkGrZ8iqDpyAdXww1e1EZYf6FRx8'); //replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

   var lastRow = ts.getLastRow();
  var numRows = range.length;
  var numCols = range[0].length;
  ts.getRange(lastRow+(lastRow > 0 ? 2 : 1), 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(SData1);

  lastRow = ts.getLastRow();
  numRows = range.length;
  numCols = range[0].length;
  ts.getRange(lastRow+2, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(SData2); // instead of the row being 1 we use the lastRow variable to continue where it left off. I added +2 to put a space between each data section, this number can be changed to +1 to remove the space.

  lastRow = ts.getLastRow();
  numRows = range11.length;
  numCols = range11[0].length;
  ts.getRange(lastRow+2, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(SData3);

}
```

Comment: Could you maybe laid an example of how you want your data to be copied in the target sheet? As right now you are  only using the variable `range` and ignoring all the defined `rangeX`. Also you could change all this variables with a `for` loop ?

Comment: Yes, correct. I only want to import items for Bob that and completed. Also, I would want to set up labels, so the data pulls. Into the correct corresponding column no matter the order. Could you provide some examples of how to accomplish this? Thank you

Comment: Please provide an example of how you want your code copied to the target sheet. Otherwise I have no way to tell how you want your data to be laid out.

Comment: Please see tab,"example of import data" on target sheet as an example of how I want data to be laid out or target sheet. You can see the sheets the data is pulling from all have different layouts. Due to all the sheets having different layouts, I would like to use match headers or labels to input the data. Target Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFRs48JHCrH82msFkGrZ8iqDpyAdXww1e1EZYf6FRx8/edit#gid=0

Comment: 1. Tags are important. If you don't tag the language your code is written in,  experts in that language won't even see your question. 2. Use clearly marked screenshots to show how you want your data moulded.  External links(docs link) are preferably avoided as it clearly exposes your email address. 3. Clearly explain what you've done so far to achieve  your goal.

Comment: Hi @retter I see that the name of the person is in a different column for every sheet. Is this your actual case or have you made this dirty and quick to create a sample sheet?